# How to rename multiple files by deleting a portion of the File name when the characters are not always the same

Tags: powershell, rename

I was hoping someone might be able to guide me in what I wish to do.

I have found a previous post that showed the following PowerShell statement that has worked wonders for me renaming some files I have in bulk.

```
get-childitem *.mp4 | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("_Title1", "") }
```

This has allowed me to rename all the files in a specific folder such that:

- Movie One_Title1.mp4
- Movie Two_Title1.mp4
- Movie Three_Title.mp4

Get renamed to the following:

- Movie One.mp4
- Movie Two.mp4
- Movie Three.mp4

I would like to see how to edit my above statement to allow me to catch and rename files that have a changing number such that:

- Movie Four_Title12.mp4
- Movie Five_Title36.mp4
- Movie Six_Title49.mp4

Can be renamed to:

- Movie Four.mp4
- Movie Five.mp4
- Movie Six.mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (untested) command should do it, using a regular expression:

```
Get-ChildItem directory | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '_Title[0-9]+','' }
```

The regular expression `[0-9]*` means:

- `[0-9]` : Any digit.
- `+` : One or more times of the previous element.
  You may use instead `*` which means "Zero or more" to get rid of `_Title` without a number.

Comment: Harrymc - This suggestion worked beautifully.  Thank you so much for the very simple edit to my original expression.  I am just a novice so I don't understand the pattern matching as well.     Again, Thank you.   It works.